# simple javascript loop click button

Tags: javascript, loops, google-chrome-extension

I am a beginner in javascript and I want to do a loop where it clicks a button, then when another button appears on the page, the loop stops and clicks the button that appeared.
(After clicking a random number of times the "`loop`" button, you can click the "`appeared`" button)
Thanks so much for your help

Button to loop: `document.getElementById('loop').click();`

Button button that appeared: `document.getElementById('appeared').click();`

Comment: do you have access to the code that makes the button appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "appeared" element is undefined, then the clicked element will be "loop", otherwise it will be "appeared".
I added a delay of 100 ms otherwise the browser may crash.

```
(function loop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    const appeared = document.getElementById('appeared')
    document.getElementById(appeared?'appeared':'loop').click()
    loop()
  }, 100)
})()
```

Comment: The script works but I would like to add exactly 3 buttons that are in the pentas and one that works after the loop is done, can you help me with that?